# Count distinct records but only 1 time every XX Days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

EDIT: Start date as of Jan 1 XXXX

I need to create a count of distinct userID's based on a 7 day grouping. Basically if a User calls on day 1 and day 2 of the month, they are counted 1 time. However if they call on Day 1 and day 10, then they are counted 2 times.

Table layout:

```
userId         CallId        datetime
0              123            01/01/2016 xx:xx:xx
0              124            01/10/2016 xx:xx:xx
1              125            01/10/2016 xx:xx:xx
1              126            01/10/2016 xx:xx:xx
2              127            01/10/2016 xx:xx:xx
1              128            01/30/2016 xx:xx:xx
2              129            01/31/2016 xx:xx:xx
```

What I need the return to look like:

```
Count(UserID)  Week#
      1          1
      3          2
      2          4
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: where should your week start for this calculation for a given year?

Comment: this depends on when you "Start" the seven day blocks. i.e., for data like {`--111---1-------1----------1--------`} the count would be different if you started at the beginning, {`--111-   --1----   ---1---   -------   1------    --`}  = 4, than it would be if you start 3 days in: {`--   111---1   -------   1------    ----1--   ------`}  = 3.

Comment: To keep it easy, I would start it on Jan 1, XXXX

Comment: I might do a Loop..... still brainstorming here.

Comment: I do not think the query should relate to UserId, but week# only based on given result. See query below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
select count(distinct userid), datepart(week, datetime) week, datepart(year, datetime) year
from my_table
group by datepart(week, datetime), datepart(year, datetime);
```

Comment: That doesn't count for his use case of a user calls twice in the same week they should only be counted once.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but this doesn't do what I am after.

Comment: @user1949329 updated. could you give it another shot?

Comment: So my total history is about 8 years of data, this will only count them once, it won't take into account multiple calls weeks apart.

Comment: you have to take year also then. I'll update the answer

Comment: I must have been reading this wrong, this does it exactly. Thank you. I tested it with one specific UserID and this was the result set

Comment: Count      Week     Year
      1      14 2016
      1      51 2016

Answer (score 1):

Based on Gurwinders response I have produced the following and included years so that it is still usuable in a years time.

```
SELECT COUNT(UserID), CallYear, CallWeek
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT UserID, 
                datepart(year,datetime) as CallYear,
                datepart(week,datetime) as CallWeek
FROM my_table
      )
Group By CallYear,CallWeek
```

Answer (score 1):

This will produce a rolling distinct count begining Jan 1

```
Declare @YourTable table (userId  int,CallId int,datetime datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(0,123,'2016-01-01'),
(0,124,'2016-01-10'),
(1,125,'2016-01-10'),
(1,126,'2016-01-10'),
(2,127,'2016-01-10'),
(1,128,'2016-01-30'),
(2,129,'2016-01-31')

Select D1
      ,D1 =DateAdd(DD,6,D1)
      ,Cnt=count(Distinct UserID)
 From  @YourTable A
 Join (Select Top 500 D1=DateAdd(DD,(Row_Number() Over (Order By Number)-1)*7,'2016-01-01') From master..spt_values ) B
   on  datetime between D1 and DateAdd(DD,6,D1)
 Group By D1
```

Returns

```
D1         D1           Cnt
2016-01-01 2016-01-07   1
2016-01-08 2016-01-14   3
2016-01-29 2016-02-04   2
```

Comment: Awesome, I will try this as well. I am moving forward with Gurwinder's example, and it appears to be working. But I want to try this one as well as I haven't done code like this yet.

Comment: @user1949329 Happy to help, with a small twist, you can define your week to be i.e. Mon-Sun

Comment: @user1949329 Just a thought, you could also have a rolling n Day window i.e. Every 10 days or even 14 days

Answer (score 0):

What is your starting date?  Have you looked at the DateDiff() function?

Comment: I have looked at Datediff, and am trying out different grouping methods for it right now. However its the Distinct part that is throwing me off

Comment: If you selected the DateDiff() using the week part, you could group on that, and select a count of the distinct userid's

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`With ABC
As
(select datepart(week, datetime) as week#
from table)
Select count(week#) as Times,week#
From ABC`